I am trying to retrieve the value of the full name field in the stripe modal, but i get undefined
Issue with Retrieving the Full Name in Stripe Checkout Modal
I am trying to retrieve the value of the full name field in the Stripe Checkout modal so that I can include it in the email I send after payment. However, the fullName is coming through as undefined in the email. I attempted to retrieve it using elements.getElement('payment').getValue(), but that didn't work. I also tried removing the field and adjusting the CSS, but the issue persists.
Below is my React component for handling Stripe payments and sending emails:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStripe, useElements, Elements, PaymentElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('your-publishable-key-here');

const sendEmail = async (paymentIntentId, email, fullName) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/send-email', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ paymentIntentId, email, fullName }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.success) {
      console.log('Email sent successfully');
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to send email');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
  }
};

const CheckoutForm = ({ clientSecret, email }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const { error, paymentIntent } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
          return_url: window.location.href,
        },
      });

      if (error) {
        console.error('Payment Error:', error);
        alert('Payment failed! Please try again.');
      } else if (paymentIntent && paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
        console.log('Payment Intent:', paymentIntent);
        alert('Payment successful!');
        
        // Retrieve full name from the payment element
        const { error: elementsError, value: { name } } = await elements.getElement('payment').getValue();
        
        if (elementsError) {
          console.error('Error retrieving name:', elementsError);
        } else {
          await sendEmail(paymentIntent.id, email, name);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in handleSubmit:', error);
      alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-4">
      <div>
        <label className="block text-lg font-medium mb-2">Payment Information</label>
        <PaymentElement options={{
          fields: {
            billingDetails: {
              name: 'auto',
            },
          },
        }} />
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="w-full py-3 bg-red-600 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg hover:bg-red-700 transition duration-300"
        disabled={loading || !clientSecret}
      >
        {loading ? 'Processing...' : 'Pay Now with iDEAL'}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

const Checkout = () => {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');
  const location = useLocation();
  const state = location.state || {};

  const { individualCount = 0, familyCount = 0, totalCost = 0, email = '' } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClientSecret = async () => {
      if (totalCost === 0) {
        console.error("Total cost is zero or undefined.");
        return;
      }

      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/create-payment-intent', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
          amount: totalCost * 100, // amount in cents
          individualCount,
          familyCount,
          totalCost,
          email,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
    };

    fetchClientSecret();
  }, [individualCount, familyCount, totalCost, email]);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-5xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 py-12">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-center mb-8 text-gray-900">Checkout</h1>
      <div className="mb-8 text-center">
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold mb-4">Total Cost</h2>
        <p className="text-4xl font-bold text-red-600">€{(totalCost || 0).toFixed(2)}</p>
      </div>
      {clientSecret && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret }}>
          <CheckoutForm clientSecret={clientSecret} email={email} />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;


fields.billingDetails.name is only collected when needed, and it doesn't get collected all the time. If the name is collected, it can be retrieved by listening to change event on the Payment Element.

If you wish to collect the billing name all the time, I'd recommend collecting it in your own form, and set the value in payment_method_data. billing_details under stripe.confirmPayment() function. Alternatively, Address Element can be used.
